# Some messages are lost in SQS

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

I'm sending and receiving messages with SQS and Java SDK. Almost all messages are working fine, but some of them are lost and I can't understand why. This is the code to send a message:

```java
final SendMessageRequest msg = new SendMessageRequest(
    this.queueUrl, data.toString()
).withMessageGroupId(projectId);
final Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> attrs = new HashMap<>(1);
// message signature - HMAC calculated from message body
final String signature = // calculating signature
attrs.put(
    "signature",
    new MessageAttributeValue()
        .withDataType("String")
        .withStringValue(signature)
);
attrs.put(
    "project",
    new MessageAttributeValue()
        .withDataType("String")
        .withStringValue(projectId)
);
attrs.put(
    "priority",
     new MessageAttributeValue()
         .withDataType("String")
         .withStringValue(priority)
);

msg.setMessageDeduplicationId(
    String.format("%s:%s", projectId, signature)
);
msg.setMessageAttributes(attrs);
Logger.debug(this, "sending message: %s", msg);
final SendMessageResult res = this.sqs.sendMessage(msg);
Logger.info(
    this,
    "message '%s' (%s) was sent: %s",
    data.id(), data.type(), res
);
```

and the code for receiving (running in a loop):

```java
final List<Message> messages = this.sqs.receiveMessage(
    new ReceiveMessageRequest(url)
        .withMessageAttributeNames(
            "project", "signature", "expires", "priority"
        )
        .withVisibilityTimeout(
            (int) Duration.ofMinutes(2L).getSeconds()
        )
        .withMaxNumberOfMessages(8)
).getMessages();
Logger.info(this, "received %d messages", messages.size());
for (final Message message : messages) {
    Logger.debug(this, "received message: %s", message);
    // actual logic here
    this.sqs.deleteMessage(
         new DeleteMessageRequest()
             .withQueueUrl(this.queue)
             .withReceiptHandle(message.getReceiptHandle())
    );
}
```

The problem is that I'm able to receive some messages, but some not (always same type of data `data.type()`). The code to send and receive is the same for all messages.
App logs:

> sending message: {QueueUrl: https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/0000000/my-queue.fifo, MessageBody:some-unique-body,MessageAttributes: {priority={StringValue: HIGH,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],DataType: String}, signature={StringValue: EXTvx7WWrZ7uTU63szJ2C4VN/6ZOiw/wKL83qW7V3i0=,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],DataType: String}, project={StringValue: PMO,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],DataType: String}},MessageDeduplicationId: PMO:EXTvx7WWrZ7uTU63szJ2C4VN/6ZOiw/wKL83qW7V3i0=,MessageGroupId: PMO}
>   message 'e29baf85-7be4-449b-824f-e405c59cf7c4' ([test]) was send: {MD5OfMessageBody: 9d6e98e0e85c8f5ca7cc4c23378dc14b,MD5OfMessageAttributes: fe94ccb1b405588e0691c91392d2c8ea,MessageId: c8ce957a-93c8-49ef-9a08-9e12cb5952b4,SequenceNumber: 18848975946990575872}
>   receiving messages: limit=8; timout=2m
>   received 0 messages
>   receiving messages: limit=8; timout=2m
>   received 0 messages
>   receiving messages: limit=8; timout=2m
>   received 0 messages
>   receiving messages: limit=8; timout=2m
>   received 0 messages

I checked that deduplication-id of these messages are always different and it has different content. How can I debug this issue deeper?

---

Update:
It seems my queue is full of messages, but I can't receive them:

```sh
$ aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url="$QURL" --attribute-names=ApproximateNumberOfMessages
{
    "Attributes": {
        "ApproximateNumberOfMessages": "1490"
    }
}
```

It's strange, since some messages are delivered in a few seconds even with full queue.

---

Update2:
I tried to use [long-polling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html#sqs-long-polling), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether is there any inflight requests for that queue in AWS console, as i can see you are using the same messagegroupid for all the messages, so the messages will be processed sequentially, if any one message is received by any consumer, until the acknowledgement of the message or visibility timeout expires, no other consumers will receive any of the messages.